# 500 (Internal Server Error) While Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<script>
    function Test()
    {
        var selected = new Array();
        $('input:checked').each(function () {
            selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        var postData = { values: selected };
    var url = '@Url.Action("ExportExcelFilesToDropBox", "Home")';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: postData,

        success: function (result) {
            if (result == "Success")
                {
                AfterCreationOfFiles(selected);
            }
            }, dataType: "json",
            traditional: true

    });


    }
    function AfterCreationOfFiles(selected)
    {
        var MyFiles = [];
        jQuery.each(selected, function (i, val) {
            if(val=="Address")
            {
                MyFiles.push({ 'url': 'http://-----/Content/File/Addresses.xlsx', 'filename': 'Addresses.xlsx' });
            }
            if (val == "DebitDetail")
            {
                MyFiles.push({ 'url': 'http://-----/Content/File/DebitDetails.xlsx', 'filename': 'DebitDetails.xlsx' });
            }
            if (val == "AddressAssociated") {
                MyFiles.push({ 'url': 'http://-----/Content/File/AddressAssociatedCompanies.xlsx', 'filename': 'AddressAssociatedCompanies.xlsx' });
            }
            if (val == "DebitDetailAssociated") {
                MyFiles.push({ 'url': 'http://-----/Content/File/DebitDetailsAssociatedCompanies.xlsx', 'filename': 'DebitDetailsAssociatedCompanies.xlsx' });
            }


        });


        var options = {

            files: MyFiles,

            // Success is called once all files have been successfully added to the user's
            // Dropbox, although they may not have synced to the user's devices yet.
            success: function () {
                // Indicate to the user that the files have been saved.
                alert("Success! Files saved to your Dropbox.");
                DeleteFiles(selected);
            },

            // Progress is called periodically to update the application on the progress
            // of the user's downloads. The value passed to this callback is a float
            // between 0 and 1. The progress callback is guaranteed to be called at least
            // once with the value 1.
            progress: function (progress) { },

            // Cancel is called if the user presses the Cancel button or closes the Saver.
            cancel: function () { },

            // Error is called in the event of an unexpected response from the server
            // hosting the files, such as not being able to find a file. This callback is
            // also called if there is an error on Dropbox or if the user is over quota.
            error: function (errorMessage) { }
        };
        Dropbox.save(options);

    }
    function DeleteFiles(selected)
    {
        var postData = { values: selected };
        var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteEXCELFiles", "Home")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: postData,

            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "Success") {

                }
            }, dataType: "json",
            traditional: true

        });



    }
</script>
```

**Above code runs successfuly on my localhost**

**But when i upload it to server then I am having the following Error, i cant understand it**

POST http://------/Home/ExportExcelFilesToDropBox 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
i.support.ajax.i.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery?v=JzhfglzUfmVF2qo-weTo-kvXJ9AJvIRBLmu11PgpbVY1:1

i.extend.ajax @ jquery?v=JzhfglzUfmVF2qo-weTo-kvXJ9AJvIRBLmu11PgpbVY1:1

Test @ Dashboard:216

onclick @ Dashboard:192
jquery?v=JzhfglzUfmVF2qo-weTo-kvXJ9AJvIRBLmu11PgpbVY1:1

 XHR finished loading: POST "http://------//Home/ExportExcelFilesToDropBox".

i.support.ajax.i.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery?v=JzhfglzUfmVF2qo-weTo-kvXJ9AJvIRBLmu11PgpbVY1:1

i.extend.ajax @ jquery?v=JzhfglzUfmVF2qo-weTo-kvXJ9AJvIRBLmu11PgpbVY1:1

Test @ Dashboard:216

onclick @ Dashboard:192
```

Comment: Add this code after `success` in `ajax` so that you can track what exactly the error is `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR.responseText)});`

Comment: syntax error in your code